# Asking a user for the capital city of Peru, South America

Tags: python, python-2.x, quiz

Can this Python code be written in a more Pythonic way?

```
'''
This scripts ask a user for the capital city of Peru, South America
'''

question = 'What is the capital city of Peru?'
answer = 'Lima'

# Ask question
print question

# Game continues as long as question is not answered
# Game ends after 3 failed attempts
end_game = False

# User has 2 attempts after entering the first wrong answer
attempts = 2

while end_game == False:
    # Get user answer
    user_answer = raw_input('Enter your answer: ').capitalize()

    # Validate users anser
    if user_answer == answer:
        print 'You got it right'
        end_game = True
    else:
        if attempts > 0:
            print 'Wrong! Try again. You have %d attempts left' %(attempts)
            attempts -= 1
        else:
            print 'You have no more attempts remaining'
            print 'The correct answer is %s' %(answer)
            print 'Oops!!! Game ended'
            end_game = True
```

Comment: your while loop looks unindented - and hence wrong.

Comment: @KobyBecker, I added some indentation on the last `if` block, to validate question and save energy us all from all full to understand of closing, reposting and stuff...

Comment: Just how funny this code looks after 8 years. Indentation was an obvious problem, and thanks to @holroy

Answer (score 8):

It's kind of a limited code section, but let us go for a review ride:

- *Have everything enclosed in `main()`* – The pythonic way of starting any code within a module is to have a main method called from the following `if` statement: `if __name__ == '__main__':`
- *Good naming of variables* – You seem to name your variables good, that is in `snake_case`
- *Not so good while loop condition* – Two slight errors here, first of all if using something like a flag it would have been better to do `while not end_game` instead of comparing against false. Even better would be to use your end of game indicator namely that there are no more attempts left: `while attempts > 0:`  (or possibly `while attempts_left:`
- *Introducing `elif`* – The combination of `else:` immediately followed by an `if` can often be better written as `elif` (which reads as *else if* something)
- *Introducing the improved `print()`* – In Python 3 the print is going to change into a function to make it everything a little more coherent, and whilst changing that, one could also get used to the [format string syntax](//docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax). Which changes `print 'answer is %s' %(answer)` into `print('answer is {}'.format(answer))`
- *Make functions multipurpose* – Often it is good to make a function multi-purpose, albeit still letting it have one primary concern. In your case this could be asking for capital cities

With all of these changes we got the code looking like:

```
'''
Ask user for what is the capital city of a given land
'''

import random

def ask_for_capital_city(land, capital_city, attempts_left = 3):
    """Ask for the capital city of a land with 3 attempts by default"""
    question = 'What is the capital city of {}?'.format(land)
    answer = capital_city

    # Ask question
    print(question)

    while attempts_left:
        # Get user answer
        user_answer = raw_input('Enter your answer: ').capitalize()

        # Validate users answer
        if user_answer == answer:
            print('You got it right')
            return True

        elif attempts_left:
            attempts_left -= 1
            print('Wrong! Try again. You have {} attempts left'.format(attempts_left))

        else:
            print('You have no more attempts remaining.')
            print('The correct answer is {}'.format(answer))
            print('Oops!!! Game ended')

    return False


def main():
    capital_cities = [
       ('Peru', 'Lima'),
       ('the UK', 'London'),
       ('the US', 'Washington DC'),
       ('Norway', 'Oslo'),
       ('Spain', 'Madrid'),
       ('Portugal', 'Lisbon'),
       ('Brazil', 'Brasilia'),
    ]

    # Your original code
    ask_for_capital_city('Peru', 'Lima')

    # Lets test for some more capital cities
    correct_answers = 0

    while ask_for_capital_city(*random.choice(capital_cities)):
        correct_answers += 1
        print('You got {} correct capital cities\n'.format(correct_answers))

    print('Goodbye!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Do extend the list at will!

***NB!** When presenting code here at Code Review, the code is supposed to work, and in your case there was a little indentation fault. A good tip to avoid that is to paste the code into the edit box, mark the entire code text and then to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> which indents the code properly.*

Comment: When it comes to [printing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13451989/1157100) in Python, [TMTOWTDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it).

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion:

- The maximum number of attempts should be a constant. Your code should reflect your design and specification: why would an information as important as the maximum number of attempts change in the name of a `print` statement?
- The `while` loop would be better off as a `for` loop because, the way I see it, you don't want it to loop until a certain a condition is met (a certain user input, for example). You actually want it to run at most three times or break out of it before if the answer is right. The `end_game` variable is, in my opinion, unnecessary.
- I think it would make the code more organized if you isolate your question in a function.

Here's the code that shows those observations:

```
def question_what_is_the_capital_of_peru():
    MAX_ATTEMPTS = 3

    print('What is the capital city of Peru?')

    for i in xrange(MAX_ATTEMPTS, 0, -1):
        if i > 1:
            answer = raw_input('Enter your answer. You have {} attempts left: '.format(i))
        else:
            answer = raw_input('Enter your answer. You have {} attempt left: '.format(i))
        answer = answer.capitalize()
        if answer == 'Lima':
            print('You got it right')
            return
        print('Wrong! Try again')

    print('You have no more attempts remaining')
    print('The correct answer is Lima')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    question_what_is_the_capital_of_peru()
```

Comment: If you're going to wrap it in a function, why not pass arguments like `question` and `answer` to add more advantage to having a function?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Sure, it's just that the OP wanted only to ask what's the capital of Peru, 3 times. If he wants a more general Quiz function, then holroy's answer above puts him in the right direction.